# perform a function when a user clicks register button in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

am kind of new to wordpress coding, am trying to edit the wp-login.php file, in which if a user clicks register button, it registers the user and stores an information on a different table in the database.. my code to insert new data into the database is below, how do i add it inside wordpress?

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('wp_classes',
array( 'userlogin' => $user_id, 'classselect' => $_POST['class_select'])
);
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
```

i added this lines of code based on what i read about hooks but nothins happened running the code

```
add_action('user_register', 'store_class', 200);


function store_class($user_id)
{
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('wp_classes',
array( 'userlogin' => $user_id, 'classselect' => $_POST['class_select'])
);
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but you should avoid editing core files such as wp-login.php where possible because as soon as you upgrade WordPress your changes will be lost. Check out [WordPress hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) instead. Hooks will enable you to do most of the things you want to do without the need to modify the core.

Comment: i was hoping to add them in a plugin later